# Cache service issue

Tags: arcgis-server

i have a map service that is cached and whe I try to access this service, I get the message displaying that downloading picture and I can see that it is trying to download and then finally get no display. When I looked in fiddler, I am getting 500 error but there are some tiles that got generated. I am not sure what is the issue. Thanks Jay

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pre-cache the areas you're interested in, because ArcGIS's cache-on-demand performance is somewhat poor, depending on your features and labels.

Remember that when you view an area that hasn't been cached, the server is actually generating a "super tile" (4096x4096) for the AOI, and your web application will probably time out waiting for the server to render and send the requested tiles in that subset.

Comment: I have cache on demand option switched off and I am pretty sure that cache exists, seems like I am having some permission issues.

Comment: It would be odd to get a few tiles returned if it were a permission issue, but certainly look in the cache directory on the server to see if all the tiles are there and permissions are set correctly.